# Windows 11 voice typing commands not working

Tags: windows-11, speech-to-text, voice-command

So I recently discovered the Windows 11 voice typing feature (Win + H) and started using it. Allegedly it supports commands like "correct word" or "select word, but it doesn't work for me. What does work for me is "new line". "Comma" only works sometimes, but many times it writes out the word "comma". Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Commands like "Select [word]" requires the application to support them. Simple text fields like notepad and browsers can really only type text in (new line is just a character). MS Word, unsurprisingly, works great with the dictation commands, so try some different editors for those features

Comment: I have only had the word 'comma' stay once, and it was probably because the voice text got interrupted before correcting it. Bad internet connection means pretty poor performance all around

Comment: What about MS Word? That's what I'm mostly using. My internet connection is pretty good, so that can't be it.

Comment: MS Word is just an example of an editor that supports all the dictation commands (Newer versions of Word have better built-in dictation though with `Alt`+`\``, which supports commands like "undo"). The Windows voice typing with `Win`+`H` uses some of those dictation features if the application supports them

Comment: If you're using Word anyways, I would suggest using the built-in Dictation features if the voice typing from Win+H isn't working well for you. If you want to use voice for applications other than word, then try out Windows Speech Recognition (a different application from the voice typing). It has to be set up the first time, but tends to work better once it's trained. There just aren't any real options for changing how the Win+H voice typing behaves